# Oozie Mutual Exclusion between two coordinators

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have two coordinators in Oozie which works on similar data files.I want to create the mutual exclusion between those coordinators such that

```
If C1 runs then C2 should wait for C1 to complete
If C2 runs then C1 should wait for C2 to complete

C1 and C1 are Oozie Coordinators.
```

Please let me know how can we do that in Oozie in terms of coordinators.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you split the things you want to do into two coordinators? If you do not want to let them work in parallel you can as well just combine them in a single coordinator/workflow and let the actions happen sequentially.

Comment: The reason for them being in two coordinator is that they both have different functionality and we dont have to do two different things at same time plus one is weekly run and another one is daily run. Mutual exclusion is required for once in week in case weekly coordinator is running then daily one should wait for it to complete.